# Insert a image in Data Base using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I need to insert a row with a Blob column which is an image got from an URL in my local hard drive. My try is:

```
File file = new File(imageURL);
FileInputStream input;
byte[] data = null;
try {
    input = new FileInputStream(file);
    data = new byte[input.available()];
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then I build my Image object: Imagen ima = new Imagen(0, data, new Date()); and I send it into another manager. I get converted the byte[] into a BLOB object like this:

```
    byte[] datos = image.getDatos();
    Blob blob = null;
    try {
        blob = conection.createBlob();
        blob.setBytes(1,datos);
    } catch (SQLException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(image.getFecha().getTime());

    String query = " INSERT INTO imagen VALUES('" + image.getId() + "','"
            + blob + "','" + sqlDate + "') ";

    int lastID = BBDD.add(query, conection);
```

I can run this without problems but I only get something like this "com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@1e1962d" and my MySQL doesn´t show my anything else.

Could anyone help me?. I use SQLyog to see it.

Thank you!!

Comment: You have another problem as well: `InputStream.available()` does **not** tell you how many bytes the input stream contains. And you are not even reading from the input stream in your code (to do that you have to call the `read()` method)

Answer (score 3):

Ok you can use prepared statement :

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps =  
                        connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE table SET file = ?");
 ps.setBinaryStream(1, new FileInputStream(file), (int)file.length());
```

**UPDATE**

The `Blob`s default `toString()` will be called which is why you are seeing such weird output, the only way would be to use PreparedStatements, please correct me if i am wring anyone.

```
public void insert() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        conn = this.connection.getConnection();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Table (image) VALUES (?)";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        if (this.file != null && this.file.canRead()) {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(this.file));
            ps.setBinaryStream(1, is, (int) this.file.length());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(1, Types.BLOB);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        FileUtil.close(is);
        DAOUtil.close(conn);
    }
}
```

And you have a connection object, you can skip BBDD this time i propose.

Comment: can you show us the code you use to insert into the database?

Comment: I can´t use preparesStatement because of the way I do the queries. Is there any way to do by using just Statement?. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Seriously, flush this answer out a little bit for future users. It is likely to get down-voted or flagged if you don't.

Comment: can you tell us why you cannot use PreparedStatement? how do your queries look?

Comment: is BBDD a public API or homegrown? it should have a interface for supporting preparedstatements.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tools only know about the types used in the fileds. A blob or similar binary field is not understood by the SQL tools and is just passed through without alteration. You will need to read this binary data into another tool that understands what the data means.

Comment: Actually, I´ve got a Java Bean called Image with an id, data and date. I build the object in the way above and then I get the info though this object to insert it in my BBDD. So you mean that before making the query I should use some other API in order to get my image well saved, son´t you?

Comment: No I mean you need to pass the data from the query to another API

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.technicalkeeda;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class InsertImageTest {

    /**
     * This is used to get the Connection
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/technicalkeeda", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured While Getting the Connection: - "
                    + e);
        }
        return connection;
    }

    /**
     * Insert Image
     */
    public void insertImage() {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            File image = new File("C:/honda.jpg");
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(image);
            connection = getConnection();
            statement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("insert into trn_imgs(img_title, img_data) "
                            + "values(?,?)");
            statement.setString(1, "Honda Car");
            statement.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream) inputStream,
                    (int) (image.length()));

            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException: - " + e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: - " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException Finally: - " + e);
            }
        }

    }

    /***
     * Execute Program
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        InsertImageTest imageTest = new InsertImageTest();
        imageTest.insertImage();
    }

}
```